# Converting PDF to text, trying to find chapters

Tags: python, pdf, text

I'm using PyPDF2 to convert a magazine (PDF) to text, this works all fine but I want to separate the chapters from each other. I was looking for patterns that occurred at the start of each chapter, but there weren't any. Does anyone know a way to achieve this?

Comment: how can you indicate chapters? do they have headers or bolded text etc.

Comment: chapters (in various documents) are usually indicated by headers. You should primarily seek this.